# Do we always test the two members of "AND" and "OR" in "IF" statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

My question is simple, if I have the code below:

```
$var = 'foo';
$var2 = 'bar';

If ($var == 'bar' && $var2 == 'foo'){
    [.. code not executed for the first condition..]
}
```

Or the code below

```
If ($ var == 'foo' || $var2 == 'bar'){
   [..code executed for the first condition...
}
```

Both IF statements have the action decided in the first condition.

The second test is executed ?

**UPDATE**

I am asking this, because I was thinking about accessing a property inside a object that may or may not exist.

So I would try something like that:

```
if ($this->object->getVar() != null && $this->object->GetVar() == 'foo'){
    [..does something if var exist and if it is 'foo'. ]
}
```

But maybe this isn't a good practice, I imagine.

Comment: Note: Compilers do not execute code, they compile it. And PHP is interpreted, which is slightly different to compilation

Comment: If the first condition is false and the comparison is `&&` then the second comparison is not done at execution time as it is not necessary

Comment: What you look for is "lazy evaluation" or "short-circuit evaluation". Most languages define not to evaluate all expressions unless necessary.

Comment: I changed the compiler reference, thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'd say that php actually uses a jit compile approach. It is _not_ a fully interpreted language.

Comment: @MatheusOliveira My answer shows an example how you could actually *check* what PHP does.

Comment: @MatheusOliveira The code in your update could be simplified to `if ($this->object->GetVar() === 'foo') { ... }` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I will try that @ThorstenDittmar It would be a relief to simplify my null checks like that. Thank you too

Comment: @arkascha Not sure thats really there yet http://news.php.net/php.internals/95531

Comment: @RiggsFolly That is, AFAIK, about the new JIT compiler (a real compiler then). That is not what I referred to. PHP>4 jit compiles scripts into bytecode which is then interpreted. The new jit compiler aims to directly compile to machine code so that the interpretation step drops away. But I am not an expert in that, I certainly may be completely wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by yourself:

```
function thisReturnTrue() {
    echo 'executed thisReturnTrue', "\n";
    return true;
}

function thisReturnFalse() {
    echo 'executed thisReturnFalse', "\n";
    return false;
}

// executed thisReturnFalse
var_dump(thisReturnFalse() && thisReturnFalse()); // false

// executed thisReturnFalse
// executed thisReturnTrue
var_dump(thisReturnFalse() || thisReturnTrue()); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operand.

If You use '`&&`' `(AND)`:

- 1st is **true** then 2nd is being tested
- 1st is **false** then 2nd is ***NOT*** being tested

If You use '`||`' `(OR)`:

- 1st is **true** then  2nd is ***NOT*** being tested
- 1st is **false** then 2nd is being tested

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects to keep in keep apart here:

**Boolean operations**

1. You can generally omit checking all remaining conditions if the boolean operator is `&&` and the currently evaluated condition is `false` already. As long as conditions are `true`, evaluation will continue from left to right.
2. You can generally omit checking all remaining conditions if the boolean operator is `||` and the currently evaluated condition is `true` already. Order is the same as for `&&`.

**Short-circuit evaluation**
But then, there are compilers or interpreters, like for example the Microsoft Dynamics NAV C/SIDE compiler, that *always* perform full boolean evaluation. That means that **every** condition is **always** checked!

In Delphi or Borland Pascal for example you can enable or disable this behaviour using a compiler directive in your code.

The default for most languages, however, is so called short-circuit boolean evaluation, which is described above.

**Unexpected side-effects**
However, you need to **know** how your compiler handles this, because it can have side effects. For example (example language, not actual syntax):

```
var x = 0;

function SomeFunction() : boolean
{
   x = 512;
   return true;
}
```

If you have a compiler that does short-cicuit evaluation, the following line would not touch `x`:

```
if false && SomeFunction() ...
```

If you have full boolean evaluation, after this line `x` would be 512, which may not be what you want!